# How can I make this sound (doesn't have to be exact

Tags: sound-design, design

I have bumped upon a sound that I need a lot.

At 00:38 you can hear the big room pluck, I'd like to make something like that.

Could someone please tell me how to make it (doesnt have to be exact, but just in that direction)

I have Sylenth1 and Massive. I have some basic knowledge about them how to make supersaws, electro basslines etc etc., I also know how ADSR works, and LFO's, but I have no idea where to begin...

I have searched on youtube for it, but didn't find any tutorial which was near that sound.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously 2 layers sounds. One Woop synth which is a sawtooth with a attack on the pitch. then i also hear some plucky sawtooth where you have 0 attack and sustain. The trick to get the width in sylenth1 is -> detune the unison on the oscillators and use very very short delays (10-40ms) with different timing for left and right channel. then also just activate the eq and play around with the frequencies (you do not need to boost or cut with the silent eq it changes/hollows out the sound by itself) and also play around with the distortion to pronounce the transient of the pluck

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is valuable information. I would never expect it to be a dual layered sound, I still have to learn a lot I see. Do you maybe have a good site where you can learn these things?

Comment: Best way to learn synthesis is to buy a cheap hardware synth or controller and then play around with the knobs (for me at least). Then make a sequence or whatever and play with the parameters. (i think turning digital knobs with a mouse isn't really intuitive ...)

Comment: Can you recommend me a cheap hardware synth or controller?

Comment: http://www.musik-produktiv.de/pic-010018071xl/akai-lpd8.jpg i use the AKAI LPD8, there is a newer versin called AKAI MPK which also has a keyboard. You can use the pads and map them to on off switches and the knobs on any knob parameter of you favourite soft synth. TAL Audio has some free vst synths witch very easy interfaces and only some knobs so you can really learn how different filter settings and osc combinations create which leads etc when you got this down, then go into modulation with adar and lfos to get some movement in the sound. Then start to automate life movements of those.

Comment: I have a Oxygen 61, is that also suited?

Comment: Ofc! Just use the Knobs and faders and Map them to the desiered Parameters!

Answer (score 1):

On Layer A just use a Saw. Then assign one of your Mod. Envelopes to Osc A pitch with Attack, Sustain and Release to minimum. Rise Mod Env Decay a bit and increase the depth until you get the right amount of pitch sweep you want. Then you can add some effects.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sawtooth wave with a short decay, some reverb, possibly dimension expander. Then the pitch seems to potentially have a small envelope on the pitch or is using the glide on a small amount. That's about it roughly.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it doesn't really come near that sound. I don't get it near as hollow sounding... Please help me. I tried a lot of things, but I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the direction you were thinking (buying the pack), but it's a pack of patches and you have Sylenth. So couldn't you get the pack, load up the patch and reverse engineer?  Then you would know exactly how it was done.

Although there's something good to be said about trying to replicate it on your own. Likely will learn something new along the way.

Comment: I have no money to buy packs, also I want to design them completely myself. I know reverse engineering is also good, but to make that sound again I have to reverse the reverse engineered method to get the same sound, that's not logical..

Answer (score 0):

There is a short pitch envelope on it too to get the very fast rise